# Flutter release apk crashing when opening the app. Debug working fine

Tags: android, flutter

[image: Log error snapshot]

```sh
Signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL), fault addr --------\n
Abort message: '[FATAL:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(234)] Check failed: vm. Must be able to initialize the VM.'
```

Comment: Have you proguard enabled?

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya yes enabled.


        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            useProguard true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt') , 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya proguard enabled but not workling.

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya Finally finded solution.ndk {
            abiFilters 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a'
        }

Works

Answer (score 0):

It may be a proguard issue. try this proguard rules.

```
#Flutter Wrapper
-keep class io.flutter.app.** { ; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugin.* { ; }
-keep class io.flutter.util.* { ; }
-keep class io.flutter.view.* { ; }
-keep class io.flutter.* { ; }
-keep class io.flutter.plugins.* { ; }
-keep class myapp.flutter.*
```